# .vimrc variables are not evaluated

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am trying to create installation script for https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/wiki/tips

```
if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  let s:downloadurl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim"
  let s:destinedirectory = $HOME . "/.vim/autoload/"
  let s:destinefile = s:destinedirectory . "plug.vim"

  if !isdirectory(s:destinedirectory)
    call mkdir(s:destinedirectory, "p")
    echo "Created directory: " . s:destinedirectory
  endif

  if executable("curl")
    silent !curl --location --fail --output s:destinefile --create-dirs s:downloadurl
  else
    silent !wget -o s:destinefile --force-directories s:downloadurl
  endif

  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
endif
```

But vim is not evaluating my variables, i.e., instead of running the command

`wget -o /home/user/.vim/plug.vim --force-directories https://raw.githubusercontent...`

It is running:

`wget -o s:destinefile --force-directories s:downloadurl`

Comment: See eg https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `execute` to evaluate the variables in commands. For your case:

```
silent execute '!wget -o '.s:destinefile.' --force-directories '.s:downloadurl
```

Here the dot is the string concatenation operator documented in `:help expr-.`.